# Using values of an array as a value in a discord embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that makes a list of players that joined the queue for a raid. When you type **!join** it is supposed to add you into the `playerlist` array (which works as intended). I then want to pass the values assigned to that array as a field in a discord message embed. When you type **!fireteam** it should show the embed displaying everyone's username who typed **!join**. It almost works as intended my only issue is that every time someone types the join command it adds the whole array again instead of the newest addition to the array.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const { default: Collection } = require('@discordjs/collection');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const playerlist = [];


const pListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#3CB371')
.setTitle('RAID')
.addFields(
    {name: 'Fireteam', value: "Players who have joined: ", inline: true}
)


function joinpug(message) {
    if(playerlist.length <= 5){
    playerlist.push(message.author.username)
    console.log(playerlist);

    pListEmbed.addFields({name: "Player", value: `**${playerlist}**` + " ", inline: true})

    }else{
        message.channel.send(pListEmbed)}
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});


client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'join') {
        joinpug(message);
    } else if(command=== `fireteam`){
        message.channel.send(pListEmbed);
    }

});


client.login('');
```

Sorry if this is an easy question I'm pretty new to JS.

Comment: [This](https://gyazo.com/48c02f64030eec6cfc6b91665852dd6d) is a picture of what the embed looks like right now if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Well If I'm not mistaken your issue is with duplicated values the quick fix for this is to use `Set` on your `joinpug`

```
function joinpug(message) {
    if(playerlist.length <= 5){
    playerlist = playerlis.push(message.author.username)
    playerlist = [...new Set(playerlist)] ;
    console.log(playerlist);

    pListEmbed.addFields({name: "Player", value: `**${playerlist}**` + " ", inline: true})

    }else{
        message.channel.send(pListEmbed)}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  When I try your answer it gives me an error that says 
 ```playerlist = playerlist.push(message.author.username)   TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.```  (If you have any more ideas as to how to fix this I would appreciate it)

Comment: just make sure to change `const playerlist` to `let playerlist`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make a new field you're adding `playerlist` as the value of the field so it adds the whole array, instead you should add the name of the author like so

```js
pListEmbed.addFields({name: "Player", value: `**${message.author.name}**` + " ", inline: true})
```